# Invariant Length Function on $n \times n$ Unitary Group

Tags: group-theory, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $1$ denote the identity of $U(n)$, the group of all $n \times n$ complex unitary matrices. Given $x \in M_n(\Bbb{C})$, define $||x|| := \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}tr(x^*x)}$; i.e., the normalized Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

If $x,y$ are $n \times n$ unitaries, why is it true that $||xy-1|| \le ||x-1|| + ||y-1||$? I'm having trouble verifying this inequality. I need to show this in order to show that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2} ||x-1||$ is a invariant length function on the $n \times n$ unitary group.

Comment: Is the $(.)^*$ the same complex conjugate operator?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz $*$ denotes the adjoint, so in the cases of matrices it is the conjugate transpose. Hence, because $x$ is unitary, by definition $x* x= 1 = x x^*$.

Comment: Made a mistake: $x^* x = 1 = xx^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x\in U(n)$, then for any $z\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ we have 
$$\|xz\|=\sqrt{\frac1n\operatorname{Tr}(z^*x^*xz)}=\sqrt{\frac1n\operatorname{Tr}(z^*z)}=\|z\|.$$
Thus, for $x,y\in U(n)$, we have
$$\|xy-1\|=\|x(y-1)+(x-1)\|\leq\|x(y-1)\|+\|x-1\|=\|y-1\|+\|x-1\|.$$